# How to find Lyapunov function?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

Show that origin is globally asymptotically stable.

$$\begin{eqnarray}
x' &=& −(x + y)^3\\
y' &=& (x − y)^3
\end{eqnarray}$$

I know to prove that $V'(x)$  has to be negative which I can prove. However, I can't seem to figure out how to get $V(x)$. Can anyone put me in right direction to how to calculate $V(x)$ for it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What is the $V(x)$?

Comment: It's a lyapunov function for the equations given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Cesareo wrote, after the change of variables
$$
u = x + y\\
v = x - y
$$
the system has the form
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{lll}
\dot u &=& v^3-u^3\\
\dot v &=& -(v^3+u^3).
\end{array}\right.
$$
I can be seen that the Lyapunov function is
$V(u,v)=u^4+v^4$: its derivative
$$
\dot V= 4u^3\dot u+4v^3\dot v
=4u^3(v^3-u^3)-4v^3(v^3+u^3)
$$
$$
=-4u^6-4v^6$$
is negative definite.

Hence, $V(x,y)=(x+y)^4+(x-y)^4$.

Answer (score 3):

Normally the characterization of a Lyapunov function is mostly an artisanal work. After a $\frac{\pi}{4}$ rotation introduced by the coordinates change

$$
u = x + y\\
v = x - y
$$

we arrive at the equivalent system

$$
\dot u = v^3-u^3\\
\dot v = -(v^3+u^3)
$$

Attached the flow chart for this system in blue, with a potential Lyapunov function showing in red the level curves.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware there are no general steps for finding Lyapunov functions, but for low dimensional systems one can look at the [stream plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=streamplot%5B%7B-%28x%2By%29%5E3%2C%28x-y%29%5E3%7D%2C%7Bx%2C-3%2C3%7D%2C%7By%2C-3%2C3%7D%5D) and try to find a contour line such that all stream lines cross that contour pointing inwards. This contour is defined by setting $V(x,y)$ equal to some constant. Often the Lyapunov function $V(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ can be a good starting guess, which would yield a circle as contour. If this doesn't work one could increase one or more of the powers from two to four, six, ect. which would make the [contour more squarish](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=contour+plot%5Bx%5E6%2By%5E6%3D1%5D) and/or perform a linear coordinate transformation which can [rotate and squash the contour](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=contour+plot%5B%282x%2By%29%5E2%2B%28y-x%29%5E2%3D1%5D). These alteration from the starting guess are usually enough when the time derivatives are polynomials, as is the case in your example.